# Keyboard for UITextView in iOS covers text I'm editing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uitextview, xcode8

I added a `UITextView` to my View in Xcode. When I run the simulation and click on the `UITextView`, the keyboard comes up. The problem is the keyboard will cover any text at the bottom of the `UITextView`. And if I keep typing eventually the text I'm typing will go below the keyboard and I can't see what I'm typing!

I'm very surprised the `UITextView` widget doesn't automatically deal with the keyboard in such a way that I always see what I'm typing or editing. How do I get this to work properly?

Comment: @rmaddy, I think you didn't understand my question. The "duplicate" question you linked to is about something different _entirely_. That's for a bunch of `UITextField`s that need to be scrolled. My issue is with a `UITextView` covered by the keyboard.

Comment: The duplicate explains how to ensure your text view (or text field) moves so it isn't covered by the keyboard.